# Why do I see so many domains from businesses without MX records?

Tags: email, mx-record

I'm doing internet servers for like 30 years now. The last three years I went back into operations and working with all the new infrastructure wonders. Feels really great. From time to time I am doing work on our mailserver that is used as a relay for customer machines. The mail queue is always a place to have a look at for things going wrong with mails.

When checking on some of the destination domains that are currently not reachable, I see a lot of domains that have no MX records set at all. My knowledge is: if you want to be reliably reachable by mail add at least two MX records of mail servers that will be able to receive mail for that domain. One master and one fall back machine. Having no MX record at all the mail server will fall back to retrieving the IP Adress of the destination mail server via the A record of its domain.

The domains in question are from businesses that are real no spam hosts or such.

These sites are misconfigured. Roughly 15 years ago such configuration would be a sure pointer to an IT department running on windows without a clue about the internet.

Did I miss anything important changes in mail configuration or is the mail misconfiguration just on the rise?

Comment: I don't understand - you mean that these companies have no MX record at all? For my understanding this would mean that they cannot (or do not want to) receive emails at all. MX record is always needed if you want to receive mails for a domain.

Comment: Not all domains have or want mail, therefore don't need MX records - some may purely be for web traffic. A company may also have several domains, but only use one for mail.

Comment: @Smock if they want no email, they should use a "no service MX" aka "null MX" https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7505

Comment: @Tobias An MX record is not needed for receiving mail. Having no MX will result in a A record lookup for the given domain.

Comment: @itsafire - never heard of that... learned something new today!

Comment: @Tobias It is described in RFC 5321 sec. 5 but very hard to read. There is a nice article of mx records on wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record See fallback to the address record.

Comment: @itsafire Yes, just did a little research about it. Strange that I never ever heard about it before... But very good to know.

Comment: @Tobias the reason is probably that you only came into contact with properly configured domains and do it properly yourself. 
Actually it's ridiculous that a standard that was introduced in the 80s(!) is still omitted by some "administrators".
Part of the reason at least here in Germany is the lack of properly trained IT-professionals; the market is dry but especially smaller companies don't want to pay wages that attract professionals. So they hire people with lackluster (if any) IT-education. And since they have no clue themselves they can't really assess the skill sets needed anyways.

Comment: @itsafire Just one addition: Not all mail servers default to the A-record, some just refuse to send mails if the MX-record is missing. I know it's in the RFC, but some mail servers still insist on an MX record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> These sites are misconfigured. Roughly 15 years ago such configuration would be a sure pointer to an IT department running on windows without a clue about the internet.

This hasn't changed much. Many companies try to cheap out on the expenses for proper IT support and have a random employee with some basic understanding of IT manage their stuff and those people tend to think that they did everything right once they are able to send and receive emails in a testing environment. Those people might be able to follow an online howto on how to set up exchange or some other random mail server software but they lack the basic understanding of DNS, especially when it comes to reverse DNS lookups, MX records etc.

> Did I miss anything important changes in mail configuration or is the mail misconfiguration just on the rise?

No, you didn't miss anything. The recent times have seen many out of the box solutions for all kinds of services and easy to use colorful UIs, including email servers which encouraged many (especially smaller) companies to cheap out on spending cash for external services and/or IT support. This caused and will keep causing multiple issues.

Some of our customers sent unencrypted emails without knowing it, some wondered why their emails don't reach certain mailservers but others work just fine (caused by DNS errors like missing MX records, lack of encryption etc.).

You don't necessarily need a fallback machine for a proper configuration, especially in smaller companies, but having no MX records at all will result in a lot of problems. So yes, you got that right.

Comment: Sad as it is. Just wanted this to be on the net :-)

But for a resilient mail server setup I would definitely like to have a fall back mail server that is not in the same network as the primary one.

Comment: “_……having no `MX` records at all will result in a lot of problems._” And may I know what problems you’re referring to? Please excuse my ignorance, but why is it that looking up `A` record instead is never enough?

Comment: @КонстантинВан for example because many Mailservers refuse to deliver mails to domains with missing MX records even though RFC says they should default to the A-record. Yahoo is one example.